# How to install Intex DC14.4SWM modem in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, internet, usb-modem

I am trying to connect my index modem with ubuntu 14.04, but didn't get to how as I also can't see any devices attached in media. Can anyone help to guide how it will work in Ubuntu?

Below is what i see on terminal after typing `lsusb&&lspci` :

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b452 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 2020:4000  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lsusb&&lspci`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Yup.  That's an "Olivetti Olicard 300" and there are no drivers for Linux.

The 200 and 500 models do have drivers (but are not standard, so it means compiling them into the kernel), so if you've just bought it, return it for the 500 model if you're a bit of a tinkerer.

Otherwise, return it for a refund and look for one in the [Ubuntu Catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/).  These are standard and "will just work".

Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news.

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea of any USB Device in which i can use my sim card to make the internet work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Have a look at the [Ubuntu Catalog](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/). Don't forget to click the grey check-mark icon to the left of this answer turning it into a beautiful green.  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask  (I have a wired and wireless connection so cannot help you any further with that)